# SELinux blocking port bind when command run via `sh -c '...'`

Tags: centos, selinux

I am trying to start a systemd user unit. The unit is a podman container that attempts to bind a port.

If I run `systemctl --user start my-service`, the container starts fine.

If I run `sh -c 'systemctl --user start my-service'` (see footnote), the container fails to boot with a SELinux error:

```
*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that a-service should be allowed create access on the port None tcp_socket by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'a-service' --raw | audit2allow -M my-aservice
# semodule -X 300 -i my-aservice.pp
```

Running the prescriped policy changes **does not** fix the issue. Disabling enforcement via `setenforce 0` **does**, so I am confident this is a SELinux issue. Indeed, if I start the container directly inside `sh -c 'podman run ...'`, I just get another different SELinux error, so I don't think chasing the policy updates is the real fix - even if they worked.

I assume this is some effect of spawning a sub-shell that isn't inheriting a policy or something, how can I fix this? I'd rather not disable SELinux.

The `export` env of both shells (top and nested) show `SELINUX_[ROLE|LEVEL]_REQUESTED=""`, but googling showed no results for those env-vars, nor could I find it in the man page.

The user is a member of `wheel`. The system is `CentOS 9 Stream`.

From what I can tell, the subshell has ok (?) policies of `unconfined_*`:

```
[deploy@host ~]$ sh -c 'ps -eZ' | grep ps
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 24356 pts/0 00:00:00 ps
```

1. I am deploying via `pyinfra` which executes its command via `sh -c '...'`, not directly via the established ssh connection, so I don't have the option to "not spawn a new shell". The above examples are performed on a "raw" ssh connection though.

Comment: Sometimes one SELinux problem masks another, meaning you can get the `ausearch | audit2allow` rules and apply them, but the same activity then still fails because there is something further it needs permission for (which it could not even attempt earlier) .   Try doing it again, then immediately afterward check `ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow ` (you will probably need superuser privilleges).

Comment: Thanks, the container is booting after running it a few times and reapplying the policy. But then SELinux started blocking DNS queries because the original tests had been hitting cached resolves, how on earth am I supposed to test for edge cases like *that*??

Comment: I've written SELinux profiles for things that did not have one, and it is pretty tedious and arcane -- avoid at all costs.  However, containers (I dunno if this includes docker, but I would guess it does) can be run on an SELinux system without SELinux being applied *inside* them (ie., `sestatus` can be `enabled` outside the container but `disabled` inside it.   SELinux will obviously apply to anything that comes out of the container, such as network traffic, but there *should* be generic docker oriented policies to cover this...

Comment: ...I can't help you with that part, unfortunately, but if you need people to poke, poke docker users.